# How to ignore duplicates from my text file using .ToDictionary, I always got the error saying: "The item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: c#, duplicates

**I got this Error:**

"The item with the same key has already been added"

Is there any other better approach?

I really appreciate anybody's help on this code

**Here's my code**

```
       string textfiletest = "C:/BSM_Command_v2.txt";
       var data = File 
       .ReadAllLines(textfiletest)
       .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
       .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
      .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);
```

**Here's my text file**

```
 RTRV-BTS_CALL_ACCESS-DATA : BTS=3~3
 M4010 RETRIEVE BTS CALL ACCESS DATA
   PRIMARY_BSC_ID        : 0                                             
   PRIMARY_BSC_RACK_ID   : 1                                             
   PRIMARY_CMP_IP_V4     : 10.233.56.133                                 
   SECONDARY_USED_FLAG   : ON                                            
   SECONDARY_BSC_RACK_ID : 0                                             
   SECONDARY_CMP_IP_V4   : 10.233.56.69                                  
   CALL_ACCESS_CONTROL_1 : 0                                             
   CALL_ACCESS_CONTROL_2 : 0                                             
   CALL_ACCESS_CONTROL_3 : 0                                             
   CALL_ACCESS_CONTROL_4 : 0                                             
   CALL_ACCESS_CONTROL_5 : 0                                             
   CALL_ACCESS_CONTROL_6 : 0                                             
   CALL_ACCESS_CONTROL_7 : 0                                             
   CALL_ACCESS_CONTROL_8 : 0                                             
   RESULT = OK
 COMPLETED


 RTRV-BTS_EVDO_CALL_ACCESS-DATA : BTS=3~3
 M4029 RETRIEVE BTS EVDO CALL ACCESS DATA
   PRIMARY_BSC_ID        : 0                                             
   PRIMARY_BSC_RACK_ID   : 1                                             
   PRIMARY_CMP_IP_V41     : 10.233.56.133                                 
   SECONDARY_USED_FLAG   : ON                                            
   SECONDARY_BSC_RACK_ID : 0                                             
   SECONDARY_CMP_IP_V4   : 10.233.56.69                                  
   RESULT = OK
 COMPLETED
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to just ignore duplicates, here is an option of grouping everything by key and selecting the first member of the group as value

```
   string textfiletest = "C:/BSM_Command_v2.txt";
   var data = File 
   .ReadAllLines(textfiletest)
   .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
   .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
   .GroupBy(x => x[0].Trim())
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First()[1]);
```

Comment: It works thank you so much, I'm new with this type of command and you are being very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Write ten lines of code and create the dictionary manually?

```
var data = File 
   .ReadAllLines(textfiletest)
   .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
   .Where(x => x.Length > 1);

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string[] parts in data)
{
    string key = parts[0].Trim();

    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        dict.Add(key, parts[1]);
    }
}
```

Note that this will "ignore" the duplicate lines and only keep the first line found for each group of lines with the same "key".

The code can even be written in a more LINQ way:

```
var data = File
    .ReadAllLines(textfiletest)
    .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
    .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
    .GroupBy(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1])
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First());
```

You `.GroupBy()` the key, and for each group you take the `.First()` value and use it in the `.ToDictionary()`

Another solution is to use the `.ToLookup()`, that returns a `ILookup<TKey, TElement>`, that is something very similar to a `Dictionary<TKey, TElement[]>`, so a multi-value dictionary:

```
var data = File
    .ReadAllLines(textfiletest)
    .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
    .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
    .ToLookup(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation you are awesome!